# Is it possible to create computational substrates from a distance?

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics, soft-question, space, distance

Processors are manufactured by photolithography, shining a light on a chemically prepared object. Layer by layer, an "active" object with computational capabilities results.

Does/can a similar process exist that manages to do this from a distance, with common substrates that have not been prepared (possibly because they are too far away for physical manipulation)?

I'm thinking of this in the context of space exploration. Transporting human bodies is incredibly difficult across interstellar distances, but could (digital) life propagate this way?

Comment: So are you asking whether we could shine carefully structured light on a distant celestial object to create digital life?

Comment: You may enjoy the opening sequence of Greg Egan's [Glory](http://outofthiseos.typepad.com/blog/files/GregEganGlory.pdf); he also touches on this theme in various other stories.

Answer (score 1):

@AgniusVasiliauskas is of course right that an instruction set is useless without something at the receiving end to interpret and execute the instructions.

However, it is not beyond possibility that a relatively low-mass "something" could be made to construct anything we can imagine at another star if we can get that "something" there.  The "something" would be a [Von Neumann Probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-replicating_spacecraft), a "universal constructor" capable of self-replication. Building a Von Neumann Probe (VNP) is a big challenge, but appears far from impossible.

Getting the Von Neumann Probe to another star within a reasonable length of time - which requires difficult acceleration to about 30% of lightspeed followed by even more difficult deceleration and guidance into an orbit around the star is probably a much bigger challenge.  The project called [Breakthrough Starshot](https://breakthroughinitiatives.org/initiative/3) proposes to send gram-scale probes to Proxima Centauri.  The mission would only result in a brief fly-by -- because there is no provision to decelerate the probes. Given an as-yet-unimagined method for decelerating such a probe and guiding it into orbit around the star, and scaling it up to allow inclusion of an ant- or mouse-sized VNP, and given a lot of patience probably spanning centuries, it is plausible that practically anything we can build here on the Earth or in the solar system eventually could be constructed at Proxima Centauri without needing to send astronauts.

Comment: That's true, and might even be the more promising/effective approach (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_panspermia details the deceleration etc. requirements well), but my question is more directed at creating computing matter remotely without mass transfer

Comment: @2080 Physics does not permit ANY instant "remote actions". Any action in the form of signal must travel at max speed $c$ to target planet/galaxy. Unless it is a particle entanglement, then affecting entangled particle A, same action instantly affects little sister B,- no matter where it is. BUT, you can't entangle Earth particle with, say Proxima Centauri b particle without having them **BOTH** in Earth lab. Thus quantum mechanics will not help here to avoid communication/travel times.

Comment: "Right" to no faster-than-light communications.    Even entanglement is not a communication channel: it and does not enable messages to be sent from a sender to a receiver.

Comment: I'm quite sure that  "creating computing matter remotely without mass transfer" would require magic.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas I'm not talking about remote actions, more about electromagnetism: light, directed lasers, any ray that can affect matter from a distance. Lasers are capable of melting/etching structures, and supplying energy to remote places.

Comment: The laws of optics make it impossible to focus laser light to a small point at long distances from any plausible-sized system.  Even a Sun-sized laser could at best focus light to a spot hundreds of meters across at the 4.2 light-year distance to the nearest star.

Answer (score 0):

Transporting any instruction-set how to build any artificial object, including processor, will travel max at $c$ speed. Besides you'll need to transport whole bunch more energy/mass to actually build a machinery remotely which could be able to manufacture something. So the answer is no - it's not way much more effective than simply transporting a group of astronauts which after $N$ generations lived in a ship could reach some star $X$.

In addition to that humans are very good at working with incomplete information, reasoning with partial information or even acting when having two opposite facts. If in a cosmic ship or (distant planet) there would happen out-of-control situation,- would you like as a passenger to be supervised by an artificial intelligence or a clever astronaut with time-tested experience and good intuition ? With technology, anything can happen which is not pre-programmed in advance in chip, so sooner or later you will need a human intervention. If no such human remotely - your mission at planet X is doomed from the start.

Comment: Transporting organisms may work on interstellar distances, but beyond our local galaxy group, this approach ceases to work, the timespans are simply too large

Comment: A way worse. Even traveling to our Milky Way galaxy borders from the Earth **at minimum** will require $65~000$ years (if one manages to flight at $c$ speed, which is impossible of course). Thus conclusion is that _ANY_ way of reaching our galaxy borders (be it human generations living in a spaceship or instruction-set passing or space-probe flight) is ridiculously silly. Unless you think about "fire-and-forget" tactics, when after emitting probe, civilization forgets it totally.  But neither it means that probe will do anything useful, nor that it will reach destination for sure.

Comment: If the sender matters at all, our or other civilizations may live on timespans much longer than that, also some organic or digital lifeforms may be capable of thinking on much slower timescales